# React Component children typecheck with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

Here is the scenario:

I have a custom component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <SuperComponent>
        <SubComponent1 />  // <- valid child
      </SuperComponent>
    )
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <SuperComponent>
        <SubComponent2 />  // <- No! It's not right shape
      </SuperComponent>
    )
}
```

and the referenced SuperComponent and SubComponent1 are:

```
interface superPropsType = {
  children: ReactElement<subPropsType1>
}
class SuperComponent extends React.Component<superPropsType> { ... }


interface subPropsType1 = {
  name: string
}
class SubComponent1 extends React.Component<subPropsType1> { ... }


interface subPropsType2 = {
  title: string
}
class SubComponent2 extends React.Component<subPropsType2> { ... }
```

I want SubComponent1 to be the only valid child of SuperComponent, that is, I wish typescript can throw an error if I place `<SubComponent2 />` or Other types as child of `<SuperComponent>`

It seems like typescript only check that the child of  should have the type of ReactElement, but ts doesn't check the shape of props of that child (which is subPropsType1), that is, if I place a string or number as child of SuperComponent, ts will complaints that type requirement doesn't meet, but if I place any jsx tag here(which will transpiled to ReactElement), ts will keep silent

Any idea ? And if any configs are required to post here, please don't hesitate to ask

Really appreciate any idea and solution

Answer (score 14):

As of TypeScript 3.1, all JSX elements are hard-coded to have the `JSX.Element` type, so there's no way to accept certain JSX elements and not others.  If you wanted that kind of checking, you would have to give up the JSX syntax, define your own element factory function that wraps `React.createElement` but returns different element types for different component types, and write calls to that factory function manually.

There is [an open suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14729), which might be implemented as soon as TypeScript 3.2 (to be released in late November 2018), for TypeScript to assign types to JSX elements based on the actual return type of the factory function for the given component type.  If that gets implemented, you'll be able to define your own factory function that wraps `React.createElement` and specify it with the `jsxFactory` compiler option, and you'll get the additional type information.  Or maybe `@types/react` will even change so that `React.createElement` provides richer type information, if that can be done without harmful consequences to projects that don't care about the functionality; we'll have to wait and see.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably declare `SuperPropsType.children` as:

```
children: React.ReactElement<SubPropsType1> | React.ReactElement<SubPropsType1>[];
```

To account for the possibility of having both a single and multiple children.

In any case, as pointed out already, that won't work as expected.

What you could do instead is declare a prop, let's say `subComponentProps: SubPropsType1[]`, to pass down the props you need to create those `SubComponent1`s, rather than their JSX, and render them inside `SuperComponent`:

```
interface SuperPropsType {
  children?: never;
  subComponentProps?: SubPropsType1[];
}

...

const SuperComponent: React.FC<SuperPropsType> = ({ subComponentProps }) => {
  return (
    ...

    { subComponentProps.map(props => <SubComponent1 key={ ... } { ...props } />) }

    ...
  );
};
```