# What type to use for Material Ui Icons when passed as props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

What type do I need when I want to pass Material UI Icons as props to a component

```
import {OverridableComponent} from "@mui/material/OverridableComponent";
import {SvgIconTypeMap} from "@mui/material";

interface IconButtonProps {
    children: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & {muiName: string};
    disabled?: boolean;
}

const IconButton = ({
                        children,
                        disabled = false,
                    }: IconButtonProps) => {
    return (
        <Button
            disabled={disabled}>
            {children}
        </Button>
    )
}
```

When I use it like this

```
import AddCircleOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddCircleOutline';

<IconButton><AddCircleOutlineIcon/></IconButton>
```

I get

> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">>'.   Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '<C extends ElementType>(props: { component: C; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial | undefined; color?: "disabled" | ... 8 more ... | undefined; ... 6 more ...; viewBox?: string | undefined; } & CommonProps & DistributiveOmit<...>): Element | null'.

I also tried

```
import {SvgIconComponent} from "@mui/icons-material";
children: SvgIconComponent;
```

giving me the same message.

Comment: 1. There is already an `IconButton` component in MUI that you can use.
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381291/react-typescript-only-allow-children-of-specific-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference of type between `AddCircleOutlineIcon` and `<AddCircleOutlineIcon />`

- `AddCircleOutlineIcon` is of type `OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & {muiName: string};`
- `<AddCircleOutlineIcon />` is of type `JSX.Element`

As mentioned in a comment, the easiest way to solve this is to use the [IconButton](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/icon-button/) Material UI component.

If you want to keep your custom component, replace the children type in your `IconButtonProps` interface by `JSX.Element`

Comment: Weid. It works. My Code Editor (IntelliJ) tells me that `<AddCircleOutlineIcon />` exports as `export default const SvgIcon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & {muiName: string}`.