# Component which prop must be an array of specific React elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write a component which accepts an array of instances of another component as a prop. That component is `MyComponent`, which accepts an array of instances of `Title` as one of its arguments. However, I am not able to get TypeScript to type check this:

```
import * as React from "react";


type TitleProps = {
    name: string;
};

function Title(props: TitleProps) {
    return null;
}

type MyComponentProps = {
    titles: Array<React.ReactElement<TitleProps>>;
}

function MyComponent({ titles }: MyComponentProps) {
    return <div>{titles}</div>;
}

function OtherComponent(props: {}) { return null }

const shouldError = <MyComponent titles={[ <div/>, <OtherComponent/> ]} />;
const shouldNotError = <MyComponent titles={[ <Title name="hi"/>, <Title name="hi2"/>, ]} />;
```

As you can see, I am able to pass whatever I want to the `titles` prop, not just instances of `<Title/>`.

[TypeScript Playground URL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwCwAUI4zAJ5hZwAqwMANlgAKxMOgC8cAN6M4suADtkILAC44qGFGDyA5vQYBffYwIBXefmAR53XgIAUYEajU9+Q5wEopMuZRimUDbypnx8+gbMDGwccACyrADCJJDyWPIwwhCicBLSDHJwMHZYLnAAglBQyKwAPNh4MAB0DfgAogLKGbVuAlmiAHwDEVFmFsXW8Ukp1ukw9pJFJegGagnJ4LMZ-aje+YX+gTa1ACbAAG4DksXuqAa1APRnlyNMDGOWkwDyMAAWWFANqk5o5nGpJAY9nBDkEFKE+HBIm9cNYNOpfhBQic2lVoLk4LV1jM0hklrcxJIANoE54PAYAGgJP3+gOJczpcAAugY4HT9Cj5GjUBisQA5CAwHHEKD4wnTTYk+A3ASoCnUnolBRKLBiMi-YBkOmMjXuLXKXX6gBMhoZXJ5fKAA)

Comment: I expect the playground to error on the last line since I'm passing a `<div/>` to `titles` which should be an array of `Title` instances like `[<Title/>, ...]`..

Comment: @DavidGomes I understand what is the error but that playground does not add anything new to the question. When you add a link to playground, people will expect they can try it there.

Comment: I think the issue is more related to the way typescript handles JSX, there is no error because any element is JSX.Element, which is also a ReactElement when we use react to handle JSX. There is no way to restrict elements by the JSX tags, since, essentially, they are the result of a function, and the props or tag no longer matter. This answer has a more detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59418019/10922948

Comment: PS why are you passing child components as props instead of nesting components/using React children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TypeScript is not a silver bullet.** There are a number of cases in which guaranteeing 100% type safety requires the introduction of additional complexity in the code, or is simply impossible. You have encountered one such situation.

There is [an open GitHub issue on the subject of typing JSX elements](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14729). Your best bet is to wait for TypeScript to introduce a specific mechanism for this.

Otherwise ([from Matt McCutchen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732266/675721)):

> all JSX elements are hard-coded to have the JSX.Element type, so there's no way to accept certain JSX elements and not others. If you wanted that kind of checking, you would have to give up the JSX syntax, define your own element factory function that wraps React.createElement but returns different element types for different component types, and write calls to that factory function manually.

So as of right now there is no way to ensure type safety for any JSX elements

Answer (score 4):

> *The feature of type safety for `JSX.Element` in Typescript is not available to us yet.*

We had this similar scenario before and what we did is instead of having an array of `JSX.Element`, we use an array of props that the same element can have. Then during render, we simply map the array of props to the array of `JSX.Element`.

```
import * as React from "react";

type TitleProps = {
  name: string;
};

function Title(props: TitleProps) {
  return null;
}

type MyComponentProps = {
  titles: TitleProps[];
};

function MyComponent({ titles }: MyComponentProps) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {titles.map(titleProps => (
        <Title {...titleProps} />
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

// no errror
const shouldNotError = (
  <MyComponent titles={[{ name: "React" }, { name: "fixme" }]} />
);

//error
const shouldError = (
  <MyComponent titles={[{ other: "don't use this" }, { another: "help" }]} />
);
```